# API 25 causing Rendering problems

Tags: android, sdk

I have Installed API 25 from SDK manager and also set the build.gradle (module app) but its showing the rendering problem 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gl4tp.jpg).. i have set the android version to 25 in xml file . . but still not working thanks in advance